# Отображение M2M поля в обоих моделях в админке Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-orm

Есть ли возможность отобразить many to many связь для двух моделей в админке django? Модели находятся в разных приложениях.

Что я пытался сделать.

library.models:

```
from article.models import Articles, ArticlesDocuments

class Documents(models.Model):
    ...
    article = models.ManyToManyField(Articles, through='ArticlesDocuments', blank=True)
```

article.models:

```
from library.models import Documents

class Articles(models.Model):
    ...
    document = models.ManyToManyField(Documents, through='ArticlesDocuments', blank=True)

class ArticlesDocuments(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Articles)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Documents)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article_articles_documents'
        auto_created = Articles
```

Но не выходит, выдает ошибку:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Articles'

Я так понимаю, это потому, что уже импортировали Documents в article.models. Как быть? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Попробуйте импортить как `from article import models as aModels`. А дальше использовать `aModels.Articles`

Answer (score 1):

`library.models`

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    ...
    article = models.ManyToManyField('article.Articles', through='article.ArticlesDocuments', blank=True)
```

`article.models`

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    ...
    document = models.ManyToManyField('library.Documents', through='ArticlesDocuments', blank=True)

class ArticlesDocuments(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Articles)
    document = models.ForeignKey('library.Documents')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article_articles_documents'
        auto_created = Articles
```

Вместо того, чтобы цитировать документацию Django для объяснения почему это так работает, просто оставлю ссылку на соответствующий раздел: [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)