# Как отобразить в ManyToMany в django.admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

Есть 2 модели "Tags" и "Posts" в файле models.py

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    # остальные поля

class Posts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, )
    # остальные поля
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank=True, related_name='posts')
```

В файле admin.py данные классы зарегистрированы

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mainApp.models import Tags, Posts

admin.site.register(Tags)
admin.site.register(Posts)
```

При создании объекта "posts" через django.admin есть возможность выбрать объекты "tags".[image]

А при создании объекта "tags". нету возможности добавить объекты "posts"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли сделать так чтобы при создании "tags" была возможность добавлять уже имеющиеся "posts"
и наоборот при создании "posts" была возможность добавлять уже имеющиеся "tags"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `TabularInline`:

```
class PostInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Posts.tags.through


@admin.register(Tags)
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Tags
    inlines = [
        PostInline,
    ]
```

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно но задачу решает на 90%.

Comment: @Kanni https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576354/